# Kotlin: Allow only parameters of the same class with generics

Tags: kotlin, generics

For a function with two parameters, I want to specify that only two parameters of the exact same class work and not of a super class. Below is an example of what I tried but didn't work in my sense because the super class Any was set by the compiler.

```
fun main()
{
    val test1 : Test1 = Test1()
    var x : Int = 5
    var y : String = ""
    test1.Test(x, y)
}
class Test1
{
    fun <T>Test(x : T, y : T)
    {

        if(x is Any)
        {
            println("Any")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call function specifying the type parameter: `test1.Test<String>(x, y)`. Anyway, `x is Any` will be always `true`

Comment: you want to ensure the types of x and y  are exactly same as  `T`or `T` or its subtypes?

Answer (score 0):

`x is Any` will always be true, since every class inherits from `Any`. You need to check the classes of `x` and `y` for equality - see below:

```
fun main()
{
    val test1 = Test1()
    var x : Int = 5
    var y : Int = 10
    test1.Test(x, y)
    test1.Test(x, "asdf")
}
class Test1
{
    fun <T: Any>Test(x: T, y: T)
    {
        if(x::class == y::class)
        {
            println("Class is same")
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Classes for parameters are not the same - got ${x::class} and ${y::class}")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you have to use `T: Any` or the class is nullable and this won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! However, my goal was to specify in the method and not at the caller of the method that the exact class of both parameters should be used for T and, if it's not the same, the code should not compile.

Comment: That's what both examples I posted do - try using a String for one of `x` or `y`

Comment: If it does not do what you want, explain why

Comment: In your examples, it is up to the caller of the method to determine the type. This can also simply set Any. But I wanted to achieve what I mentioned in my comment above. Also so that I am not dependent on the caller of the method, but only on the method itself.

Comment: My goal was not that an if query checks whether both classes are the same, but that the program does not compile at all if both variables are not of the same type. Just like trying to assign an int object to a string variable

Comment: @YannickStrauss if the `T` must be `Any`, you cannot catch that during the compilation time. What you can do is, check the type in the method body and throw an exception if the types don't match. Or, you can define your concrete type `T` instead of `Any` For example `<T:Number>`

Comment: You can't do what you want at compile time